# Как сделать так чтобы в коде mouseMoveEvent работал без нажатой клавиши мыши

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

Код выводит на экран фигуры в зависимости от нажатой кнопки, При нажатии левой кнопкой мыши на форме рисуется круг произвольного размера и цвета в точке, где находится курсор
При нажатии правой — квадрат произвольного размера и цвета
Если была нажата клавиша «Пробел» — там, где располагается курсор, должен появиться треугольник также произвольного размера и цвета.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPolygon
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt, QPoint
from PyQt5.QtGui import QPainter, QColor
from random import choice, randint
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.resize(500, 500)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 500, 500))
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle("Супрематизм")


class Main(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.x = -1
        self.y = -1
        self.k = 0
        self.colors = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Cyan',
                       'Blue', 'Magenta', 'Purple', 'Brown', 'Black']

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        self.x = event.x()
        self.y = event.y()
        if event.button() == Qt.LeftButton:
            self.k = 1
        elif event.button() == Qt.RightButton:
            self.k = -1
        self.update()

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == Qt.Key_Space:
            self.k = 2
            self.update()

    def mouseMoveEvent(self, event):
        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.x_coor = event.x()
        self.y_coor = event.y()
        print(self.x_coor, self.y_coor)

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        qp = QPainter()
        qp.begin(self)
        self.drawing(qp)
        qp.end()

    def drawing(self, qp):
        if self.x > -1 and self.y > -1 and self.k == 1:
            qp.setBrush(QColor(choice(self.colors)))
            qp.drawRect(self.x, self.y, randint(1, 100), randint(1, 100))
            ex.show()

        elif self.x > -1 and self.y > -1 and self.k == -1:
            qp.setBrush(QColor(choice(self.colors)))
            a = randint(1, 100)
            qp.drawEllipse(self.x, self.y, a, a)

        elif self.x > -1 and self.y > -1 and self.k == 2:
            qp.setBrush(QColor(choice(self.colors)))
            width = randint(20, 100)
            points = QPolygon([QPoint(self.x, self.y), QPoint(self.x  + width,
                                      self.y + width),
                               QPoint(self.x  - width,
                                      self.y + width)])
            qp.drawPolygon(points)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(argv)
    ex = Main()
    ex.show()
    exit(app.exec())
```

В коде mouseMoveEvent работает только с зажатой клавишей из-за чего программа может рисовать треугольник только на месте предыдущей фигуры, как это можно исправить?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Добавьте `self.setMouseTracking(True)` и `self.centralWidget().setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)` в конструктор.

Причина в том, что `centralWidget` загораживал область родителя ([ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9638865/5909792)). Если бы на окне не было бы других виджетов, то не нужно будет им указывать `.setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)` (для рисования можно сделать просто `QWidget` с переопределенными методами для рисования, а его уже добавить, например, в `QMainWindow`)

Пример:

```
...
class Main(Ui_MainWindow, QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.x = -1
        self.y = -1
        self.k = 0
        self.colors = ['Red', 'Orange', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Cyan',
                       'Blue', 'Magenta', 'Purple', 'Brown', 'Black']

        self.setMouseTracking(True)
        self.centralWidget().setAttribute(Qt.WA_TransparentForMouseEvents)

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
...
```

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: @Cilc, пожалуйста :)